# How would this RC Circuit behave ?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I am new to electronics and have been understanding RC circuits recently. But I can't seem to understand some of the things. In this circuit below, say I have a Square wave input at some frequency(f) , Now what would be the voltage at the Output terminal ?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTGsnN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here is my understanding: Assuming the duty cycle is 50% and is on for a period where ON time < C charge time.

**Case 1:** With only the capacitor, I understand it will charge at the constant ON part and then discharge at the constant Off part.

**Case 2:** But now if we connect a resistor in parallel. How do things change with respect to what happens to the signal then ?

Comment: Guess what: the behaviour depends on the actual values. Try a simulator.

Comment: The "input" impedance matters, so does the frequency, so do the values of the parts, as does what is connected to the "output" as a load. But if the output is open like you have it, and if we discount any RF emissions, then the output will just follow the input around since it can't do anything else.

Comment: @jonk Thanks for the reply. My main concern is why does it matter. Whats the analysis you guys are doing in your mind that makes you think those are required ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the circuit: -

[image]

> say I have a Square wave input at some frequency(f) , Now what would
>   be the voltage at the Output terminal ?

It would be exactly what is inputted. All you have is a signal generator and a series impedance (formed by R||C) and this impedance will **not** develop any volt drop across it because there is no current passing from the input to the output. This ensures that the output = the input.

> Case 1: With only the capacitor, I understand it will charge at the
>   constant ON part and then discharge at the constant Off part.

No, there will be **zero** charging and discharging because there is no current flow.

> Case 2: But now if we connect a resistor in parallel. How do things
>   change with respect to what happens to the signal then ?

Nothing changes because you have no current flow.

Answer (score 0):

Good day. The output will be equal to the square wave input because the circuit is practically an "open circuit" ; no current flows through.  No attenuation of the input square wave, no voltage drop across the parallel R1C2.  The case would have been different if you terminated the circuit with a resistor or any form of load at the output.
 If the circuit was terminated with say another resistor "R" at the output, then we should expect a periodic voltage waveform at the output. The output voltage may be attenuated depending on the frequency of the input square wave. This is because the impedance of the parallel R1C2 is "frequency dependent".  If frequency of input signal is "extremely" high and the capacitive reactance of C2 is far less than R1, then R1 will be effectively short-circuited and the impedance of R1C2 lump will approach zero. This causes the entire input voltage to appear across the load "R".
However, at other intermediate frequencies of input supply, the impedance of R1C2 lump will be substantial. This causes the output voltage to be less in magnitude than that of the input.